# can't reset password from centos

Tags: centos, password-recovery, reset, shadow, inittab

I lost the root password. So I modified /etc/shadow and also changed '/etc/inittab' file to access single user mode. But both didn't work. It asked me for a password that I don't have. Why updating the two files doesn't work?

---

I mount the file system, then overwrite the old shadow file with a new shadow file. I'm sure the password hash and format is right. But sometimes I receive error msg like this:

"
EXT4-fs error (device vda1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy: EXT4-fs: group 0: 22415 blocks in bitmap, 22416 in gd
Login timed out after 180 seconds
"

or error msg like this:

"
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /] fsck.ext4 -a /dev/vda1 
/dev/vda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/vda1: Duplicate or bad block in use!
/dev/vda1: Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 131094: 558941
"

Answer (score 4):

How did you "modify `/etc/shadow`"? You should be able to copy a user's password hash from `/etc/shadow` from one a system on which you know the password "works" to this server's `/etc/shadow` and have it Just Work (TM).

Oh, and don't edit `/etc/shadow` directly. Instead, use `vipw -s`. That will help prevent you from saving the file with formatting errors.

Comment: Looks like the moderator moved my reply to the top. Do you have a resolution to the issue based on the way I operate shadow file as described above?